# why initator seems missing logon response and can't build a stable session?

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol

my FIX initiator today didn't get any message in default time and sent TEST message to Acceptor for testing the session if active or not, and not got HEARTBEAT response, so it believed the session was broken, then disconnecting the session and initiated a LOGON Request,
while not get logon response from acceptor, while acceport seems having sent the reponse. what could be the problem. I am using QuickFIXJ and FIX 4.2

the followings are event log:

**initator event log:**

```
20121010-05:00:46: Sent test request TEST

20121010-05:01:13: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for heartbeat

20121010-05:01:14: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:01:25: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:01:26: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:01:36: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:01:37: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:01:48: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:01:49: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:02:00: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:02:01: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:02:12: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:02:13: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:02:24: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:02:25: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:02:35: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:02:36: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:02:46: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:02:47: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:02:57: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:02:58: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:03:08: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:03:09: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:03:19: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:03:20: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:03:30: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response

20121010-05:03:31: Initiated logon request

20121010-05:03:42: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response`
```

**Acceptor event log:**

```
20121010-05:01:14: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33536

20121010-05:01:14: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:01:14: Received logon

20121010-05:01:14: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:01:26: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33557

20121010-05:01:26: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:01:26: Received logon

20121010-05:01:26: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:01:37: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33585

20121010-05:01:37: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:01:37: Received logon

20121010-05:01:37: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:01:49: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33605

20121010-05:01:49: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:01:49: Received logon

20121010-05:01:49: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:02:01: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33616

20121010-05:02:01: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:02:01: Received logon

20121010-05:02:01: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:02:13: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33645

20121010-05:02:13: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:02:13: Received logon

20121010-05:02:13: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:02:25: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33667

20121010-05:02:25: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:02:25: Received logon

20121010-05:02:25: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:02:36: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33695

20121010-05:02:36: Acceptor heartbeat set to 30 seconds

20121010-05:02:36: Received logon

20121010-05:02:36: Responding to logon request

20121010-05:02:47: Accepting session FIX.4.2:FIXNETWORK->NEOBSS from /192.168.107.6:33723
```

**initiator msg log**

```
8=FIX.4.29=7035=134=62749=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:00:46.61256=FIXNETWORK112=TEST10=028

8=FIX.4.29=7135=034=915149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:46.61356=NEOBSS112=TEST10=078

8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:46.67856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:00:45.274207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=202
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:46.89756=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:00:45.274207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=207
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:47.13056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:00:45.274207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=190
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:00.52256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=121
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:00.74656=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=129
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:00.97956=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=120
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.20256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=100
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.43856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=190
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.65956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=186
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.87956=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=193
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:02.09556=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=184
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=62849=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:14.71356=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=053
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=916349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.71656=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=108
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.71856=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=191
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.71956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=192
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.72056=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=127
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.72156=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=110
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:15.61256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=139
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:15.83256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=125
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=917049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.06256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=133
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.28456=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=197
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.50456=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=194
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=917349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.74256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=122
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.98256=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=206
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:17.24656=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=202
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=62949=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:26.61356=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=056
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=917649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61556=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=113
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61756=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=206
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=207
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=917949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61956=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=151
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61956=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=124
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:30.53056=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:30.281207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=120
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:30.77156=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:30.281207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=129
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.00756=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=104
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.24856=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=113
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.48656=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=194
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.70656=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=191
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.92056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=190
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:32.13456=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=190
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63049=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:37.61756=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=054
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=918949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.61856=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=122
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=188
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62156=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=189
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:30.281207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=132
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62356=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=116
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:45.55556=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:45.284207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=146
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:45.77556=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:45.284207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=152
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:45.98356=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:45.286207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=136
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.21556=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:45.286207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=127
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.43956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=213
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.67256=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=214
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.89656=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=205
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:47.14356=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=193
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63149=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:49.61756=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=058
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=920249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:49.61856=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=111
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:49.62056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=197
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:49.62156=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=198
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=920549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:49.62156=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:45.284207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=138
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=920649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:49.62256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:45.286207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=123
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=920749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:00.52756=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:00.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=128
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63249=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:02:01.61656=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=047
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=920849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:01.61856=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=106
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:01.61956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:00.288207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=192
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=921049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:01.62056=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:00.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=116
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=921149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:01.62156=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:02:00.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=099
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=921249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:01.68756=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:00.288207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=190
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=921349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:01.94356=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:00.288207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=188
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=921449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:02.18356=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:00.288207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=185
8=FIX.4.29=29835=834=921549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:04.19356=NEOBSS1=ROCIM006=6.2800002098083511=N117204414=50017=N2012101089650000008400020=031=6.2832=50037=N117204438=1000039=144=6.2854=155=0198860=20121010-05:02:03.945150=1151=950020036=NEO117204420059=896520060=638920064=13020410=039
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63349=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:02:13.61656=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=051
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=921749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:13.61756=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=108
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=921849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:13.61956=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:00.288207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=195
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=921949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:13.62056=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:00.288207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=187
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=922049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:15.53756=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=129
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=922149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:15.75756=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=135
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=922249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:15.97756=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=121
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=922349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:16.20156=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=180
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=922449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:16.40256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=106
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=922549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:16.60956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:15.291207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=194
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=922649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:16.84156=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:15.291207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=195
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=922749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:17.07756=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:15.291207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=197
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63449=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:02:25.61256=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=051
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=922849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:25.61356=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=109
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=922949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:25.61556=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:15.291207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=196
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=923049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:25.61656=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:15.291207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=188
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=923149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:25.61656=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=131
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=923249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:25.61756=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:02:15.290207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=113
8=FIX.4.29=29835=834=923349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:26.22056=NEOBSS1=ROCIM006=6.2800002098083511=N117204414=1000017=N2012101089650000008600020=031=6.2832=900037=N117204438=1000039=244=6.2854=155=0198860=20121010-05:02:25.969150=2151=020036=NEO117204420059=896520060=241720064=13022610=026
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=923449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:30.55256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:30.293207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=128
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=923549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:30.77356=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:02:30.293207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=135
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=923649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:31.00156=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:02:30.293207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=101
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=923749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:31.23856=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:02:30.293207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=115
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=923849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:31.46956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:30.293207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=198
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=923949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:31.71856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:02:30.293207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=197
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=924049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:31.95356=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:30.294207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=191
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=924149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:32.20656=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:30.294207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=185
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63549=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:02:36.61656=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=058
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=924249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:36.61756=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=111
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=924349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:02:36.61956=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:02:30.294207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=199
```

Acceptor msg Log:

```
8=FIX.4.29=7035=134=62749=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:00:46.61256=FIXNETWORK112=TEST10=028
8=FIX.4.29=7135=034=915149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:46.61356=NEOBSS112=TEST10=078
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:46.67856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:00:45.274207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=202
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:46.89756=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:00:45.274207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=207
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:00:47.13056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:00:45.274207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=190
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:00.52256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=121
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:00.74656=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=129
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:00.97956=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=120
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=915849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.20256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=100
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=915949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.43856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=190
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.65956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=186
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:01.87956=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=193
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:02.09556=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=184
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=62849=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:14.71356=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=053
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=916349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.71656=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=108
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.71856=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=191
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=916549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.71956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=192
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.72056=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=127
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:14.72156=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:00.276207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=110
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:15.61256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=139
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=916949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:15.83256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=125
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=917049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.06256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=133
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.28456=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=197
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.50456=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=194
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=917349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.74256=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=122
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:16.98256=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=206
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:17.24656=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=202
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=62949=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:26.61356=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=056
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=917649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61556=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=113
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61756=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=206
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=917849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61856=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=207
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=917949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61956=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=151
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:26.61956=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:15.279207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=124
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:30.53056=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:30.281207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=120
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:30.77156=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:30.281207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=129
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.00756=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=104
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=918449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.24856=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=113
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.48656=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=194
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.70656=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=191
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:31.92056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=190
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=918849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:32.13456=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=190
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63049=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:37.61756=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=054
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=918949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.61856=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=122
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62056=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=188
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62156=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=189
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62256=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:30.281207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=132
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919349=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:37.62356=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:30.282207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=116
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919449=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:45.55556=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:45.284207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=146
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919549=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:45.77556=NEOBSS55=EEE60=20121010-05:01:45.284207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=152
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919649=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:45.98356=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:45.286207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=136
8=FIX.4.29=13635=f34=919749=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.21556=NEOBSS55=GGG60=20121010-05:01:45.286207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=127
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919849=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.43956=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=213
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=919949=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.67256=NEOBSS55=MMMM60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=214
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920049=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:46.89656=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=110=205
8=FIX.4.29=13735=f34=920149=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:47.14356=NEOBSS55=NNNN60=20121010-05:01:45.287207=XXXX20067=CT20068=N20069=Y20070=210=193
8=FIX.4.29=7335=A34=63149=NEOBSS52=20121010-05:01:49.61756=FIXNETWORK98=0108=3010=058
8=FIX.4.29=7435=A34=920249=FIXNETWORK52=20121010-05:01:49.61856=NEOBSS98=0108=3010=111
```

**Msg logs show that client logon frequently, and why?**

Comment: Provide the logon FIX message and the response from the server. Log the FIX message the server sends and provide a sample. Chances are your config may also be wrong.

Comment: Event logs suck.  Please paste from your message logs; I bet we'll see rejects or something in there that will be helpful.

Comment: thanks @DumbCoder, I will add msg logs later, this problem didn't always happen, it happened randomly. it encounted this problem probably after couples of days, weeks or monthes

Comment: thanks @GrantBirchmeier, I will add msg logs later

Comment: @Cruis Also it is kinder to the community to actual find the problem yourself and narrow it down - I spend all day finding problems in logs with FIX and FIX/FAST and dozens of other protocols from various exchanges - ask a concise question please

Comment: @AdrianCornish agree with that, I asked here just in case someone alreay encounted this issue before, and I am also keeping tracking this problem, not just site here warting for answers.

Comment: These 2 logs are both from the same side of the connection (SenderID=FIXNETWORK).  Please correct with logs from the other side.

Comment: I am also facing this problem today, If anyone find the solution they please respond.